# Call to undefined function get_editable_roles()

Tags: wordpress

For some reason, I can't get working the WordPress function get_editable_roles(). Is there a bug with this? <strike>Doesn't mind where I add, in the functions.php, in the index.php, in the top, in the bottom. It always gives the undefined function error.</strike>

I added this line of code in Twenty Fifteen theme, in a fresh WordPress install and without any plugin:

```
$role = get_editable_roles();
```

It give this error:

> Error: Call to undefined function get_editable_roles()...

If I load the user.php file before, then it works:

```
if (!function_exists('get_editable_roles')) {
   require_once(ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/user.php');
}
```

Comment: Please share the relevant code...This is only loaded in Admin sections, so you're going to need to use it in the appropriate action hook.

Comment: There is no relevant code, I am simply adding $role = get_editable_roles() in functions.php

Comment: ...Again, that function is only loaded in the Admin. If you want to use it elsewhere, you should implement your own version of the function. If you want to use it in the Admin, you should make sure you're calling the function via an admin action hook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're trying to use this function outside the admin section where it isn't loaded.

From the Wordpress documentation:

> **Notes**
>   The file that defines this function (wp-admin/includes/user.php) is only loaded in the admin sections.

See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_editable_roles

Comment: the file functions.php is not loaded in the admin? I think yes

Answer (score 7):

You should consider to load **user.php** even you are in admin side, especially you have created a custom admin page like options.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'get_editable_roles' ) ) {
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/user.php';
}

$roles = get_editable_roles();
```

It is also discussed [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-get_editable_roles-1/?replies=13).